# Cypress click doesn't trigger the action

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I have a product page with the product quantity control element and the price. On the website, when I click the increase qty button `+`, the price changes accordingly.

But when I do it with Cypress, I can click the increase button, the product qty changes but the price stays the same. Like if the event was never triggered.

Is there is something like `toHaveBeenCalledWith` or any listeners I should add to the flow?

Piece of my code:

```
describe("checkout", describeCheckout);

function describeCheckout() {
  beforeEach(() => {
    populateCart();
    cy.loginUi();

    cy.visitPath("/checkout");
    cy.wait(3000);
  });

  // This part works
  it("should click increase button on item", increaseItemQty);
}

function increaseItemQty() {
  cy.get("increase-qty").click()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the HTML for the `+` button.

Comment: Hi. Will be great to have the HTML and run logs for a better understanding. Try to trigger the event by its name: `cy.get("increase-qty").trigger('click')`

Comment: 1. include the code for the function that updates the price. 2. put a log there and see if it's called, and if there's an error. 3. check in the cypress window on the left if the API call that will result in updating the prices actually fires. 4. the title of the question is wrong. It DOES trigger the action (increase the qty). There's a problem further down the line in the function it calls.

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below:

```
describe("checkout", describeCheckout);

function describeCheckout() {
  beforeEach(() => {
    populateCart();
    cy.loginUi();

    cy.visitPath("/checkout");
    cy.wait(3000);
  });

  // This part works
  it("should click increase button on item", increaseItemQty);
}

function increaseItemQty() {
  cy.get("increase-qty").scrollIntoView().click({ force:true })
}
```

Comment: the click is working, as shown by the fact the qty displayed goes up to 2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).